# Need a vba module to apply drop-down list box validation for two columns in a set of excel spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba, module, listbox, activex

I have written something but it only works (sort of) on one spreadsheet, but I have 18 each month and my aim is to write one module and import it into all of them each month. The one that sort of works starts at row 4 for some reason instead of row 2.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()


With dataValKeep()

    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht = Sheets("Inventory_Risk_beta1")
    lrow = Sheets("Inventory_Risk_beta1").Cells(Sheets("Inventory_Risk_beta1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

      With sht.Range("AN2:AN" & lrow).Validation
           .Delete
           .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="Rework,Shelf Life Extension,Change in Demand,Quality Issue,End of Life,NPI,Transfer and Charge,Older Lot / Batch,Other"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
        End With

End With

With dataValScrap()

    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht = Sheets("Inventory_Risk_beta1")
    lrow = Sheets("Inventory_Risk_beta1").Cells(Sheets("Inventory_Risk_beta1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

      With sht.Range("AO2:AO" & lrow).Validation
           .Delete
           .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="Rework,Shelf Life Extension,Change in Demand,Quality Issue,End of Life,NPI,Transfer and Charge,Older Lot / Batch,Other"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
        End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What are `With dataValKeep()` and `With dataValScrap()`?

Comment: one listbox for each column (column names are 'Keep' and 'Scrap').

Comment: Copying and pasting this code into a new module in another spreadsheet results in  no listbox on any row or column, i.e., 100% nothing.